# DateTimePicker validation for VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, validation, datetime

I'm trying to do this:

```
If DateTimePicker1.Value.Date = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date Then
        MessageBox.Show("You have not entered a date of birth yet.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

While my DateTimePicker value is `2016-01-01`, when passed all validation checks, The error above still shows up, even when I have changed the value of the date.

How does this happen?

Comment: `DateTimePicker1.Value.Date` will always be equal to itself. What should you be comparing it to?

Comment: OH YEAH I JUST REALISED LOL. @AndyG I'm comparing it to 2016-01-01, the initial value of the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    If DateTimePicker1.Value.Date = New Date(2016, 1, 1) Then
        MessageBox.Show("You have not entered a date of birth yet.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.

My own solution which i did was to `Dim InitialDate As String` and when the form loads `InitialDate = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString`

Your code made mine simpler a whole ton.

Comment: Umm what happens if the user enters a data of birth that is 2016,1,1?

Comment: You might be better setting the date of the DateTimePicker to today's date. and checking for that instead.